# How can I assign multiple IPv6 addresses with DHCPv6 to a single interface?

Tags: linux, dhcp, ipv6, pcap

This seems to be possible based on the spec [rfc 3315 page 23](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3315#page-23):

Excerpt:

> The configuration information in an IA consists of one or more IPv6
> addresses along with the times T1 and T2 for the IA.  See section
> 22.4 for the representation of an IA in a DHCP message.

Yet, I haven't been able to configure my DHCPv6 client to request these multiple IP addresses on an interface.

Does anyone know how to do this for a Linux DHCPv6 client (preferably running RedHat 6+, CentOS 6+, or Fedora), or on Windows?

My end goal is to do some testing with PCAP files.  I would prefer to be able to generate these files myself, but if I can't get my client configured, I would like to find some PCAP files on the internet that I could use.  So far, I haven't found anything.

Thanks!

Comment: My 2 cents: Every DHCPv6 Client I've used so far is notably lacking in feature completeness. I would not be surprised if most do not support requesting multiple IA addresses.

Comment: The standard dhclient seems to be supporting multiple addresses already. Did you set DHCPV6C=yes in the network card ifcfg script?

Comment: If the dhcp client doesn´t support this feature yet, you can add an Interface alias, I don´t know if you al look for this.

Comment: @POLLOX Interface aliases are not supported with IPv6. Instead with IPv6 you can assign multiple addresses directly to an interface. But I have no idea if you can get an DHCPv6 client to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but here's what I think would work:

Use `brctl addbr` to create a virtual switch.  Create two virtual interfaces (with commands like `ip tuntap add mode tap`).  Then add both tap interfaces and your physical interface to the bridge (e.g. `brctl addif tap0`).  Now you have two interfaces on which to run dhcp clients.

Comment: Interesting, I will look into this.